# why my slideshow using jQuery is not working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have read a tutorial and implemented it to show a image slide using jquery..but i couldn't find out the actual reason why it is not working..
my aspx code

```
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="icon/7.jpg" class="active" />
<img src="icon/contestpic.PNG"  />
<img src="sgipc/pic/contestpic.jpg" />
</div>
```

my javascript code

```
function slideSwitch() {
      var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
      var $next = $active.next();

      $active.addClass('last-active');

      $next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })
          .addClass('active')
          .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000, function () {
              $active.removeClass('active last-active');
          });
  }

  $(function () {
      setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
  });
```

my css

```
#slideshow {
position:relative;
height:350px;
border:1px solid green;
}

#slideshow IMG {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:8;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
z-index:9;
}
```

Comment: Explain 'not working'! Any error in console?

Comment: no error in the console..only my first image is there..it's not sliding..

Comment: is there any other problem in my code??

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: will my pics of my harddrive work in jsfiddle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WRONG**

```
  $(function () {
      setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
  });
```

**RIGHT**

```
  $(function () {
      setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);
  });
```

Comment: I mean they both work just fine, the first one works just fine, but it eval's the function so the second one is preferred, but it's not an error per se.

Comment: @setu - they both work fine, this is not the issue with your code.

Comment: what can i do now?? :(

Comment: my code is doing fine in jsfiddle but in visual studio why it is not working??

Comment: i am working in localhost in visual studio..is there any problem there??or i have to do anything in pageload().. sajithnair,adeneo

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you call that function in code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "slideSwitch", true);
```